# How to query Azure Digital Twin from Power BI?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-digital-twins

I am trying to query the REST-API of my Azure Digital Twins instance for the full spacepath of a given space from PowerBI.

The aim of this try is, to get a hierarchy of my space for a report in PowerBI. To stay with the Microsoft-tutorial, if I query for the a specific Raspberry I would like to get Campus/Building/Floor/Room where the Raspberry is located. 
This information would be of big use for a better understanding of the reports information and context.

Has anyone done something similar already?

Thx in advance!
Regards, Fabian

Comment: @Fabain a new version of Azure Digital Twins is coming. If you are still trying to leverage version 1, did you explore swagger [GET /api/v1.0/spaces/{id}/values](https://docs.westcentralus.azuresmartspaces.net/management/swagger/ui/index#/Spaces/Spaces_GetValue) ?

Comment: Hi @asergaz, yes I know there is a new version and I also know the swagger API of my Azure Digital Twins instance.
As far as I know, Power BI is able to make REST calls. But not at runtime, only cyclical. So If I want to get the hierarchy of a specific meassurement, I have to do a cyclic call of all elements.